# How to solve expression with /=

Tags: java, expression

I need help understanding how to solve the following:
482/10/5/2.0*2+14/5

I understand needing to do PEMDAS and that 2.0 makes the answer a double but somewhere I'm messing up and I cannot for the life of me figure out where. I know the answer is 11.0. Can someone please write it out for me how to get to that answer?

So far I multiply the 2.0 * 2 and that give me 4.0 and then divide across. 482/10 is 48 and then 48/5 is 9 and 9/4.0 is 2.0 and 14/5 is 2. So then you have 48/9/2+2 =4 or you have 4.0. Neither obviously is 11.0. So I'm confused where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should show us what you have so far, so we can help modify your code to help out. You'll get better feedback and better responses!

Comment: So I multiply the 2.0 * 2 and that give me 4.0 and then divide across. 482/10 is 48 and then 48/5 is 9 and 9/4.0 is 2.0 and 14/5 is 2. So then you have 48/9/2+2 =4 or you have 4.0. Neither obviously is 11.0. So I'm confused where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Go in order from left to right. It will be rounded until you multiply the double. 482 / 10 = 48 not 48.2 because it is still integer division.

Comment: @AyshaHopper could you post your code in the question?

Comment: @ChrisGilardi I don't have code for it. I'm trying to understand expressions in my coding class and I'm studying for my midterm. This is a question on my review that I'm struggling with as we have to do all coding on paper for the test and I have to be able to solve the expressions with no calculator or computer.

Comment: `System.out.println((482 / 10 / 5 / 2.0 * 2) + (14 / 5));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `482/10/5/2.0*2+14/5`
2. `48/5/2.0*2+14/5`
3. `9/2.0*2+14/5`
4. `4.5*2+14/5`
5. `9.0+14/5`
6. `9.0+2`
7. `11.0`

Divisions go from left to right, addition comes last. An integer is only converted to double in an arithmetic operation with a double. That only happens three times: In step 3 (`9/2.0`), step 4 (`4.5*2`) and step 6 (`9.0+2`). All other operations are pure integer operations.

Answer (score 0):

(((((482/10)/5)/2.0)*2)+(14/5))

Comment: Please try to be more descriptive in your explanation.